# Find the derivative of $x(t) = \int_0^t \lambda^{t-\tau} y(\tau) d\tau$ in one step

Tags: integration, derivatives

> Given $$x(t) = \int_0^t \lambda^{t-\tau} y(\tau) d\tau$$
> where $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}_{>0}$
>
> Find $\dot x(t)$

**Claim: The answer can be obtained in one step yielding $\dot x = y - \log(1/\lambda) x$**

Comment: Have you learned about convolutions?

Comment: @Triatticus how this be looked at as a convolution?

Comment: The above integral is a convolution $\lambda^t * y(t)$

Comment: @Triatticus it is not. The convolution of that is $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \lambda^{t - \tau} y(\tau)d \tau$

Comment: For some reason I assumed y to disappear at zero

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$x(t) = \lambda^t \int_0^t \lambda^{-x} y(x)dx$$

Assuming that $y$ is a continuous function, we have by the fundamental theorem of calculus:

$$x'(t) = (\ln \lambda) x(t) + \lambda^t(\lambda^{-t} y(t)) = (\ln \lambda) x(t) + y(t)$$

Comment: Damn it I see it now the reciprocal on the log! You are not stupid you deserve to live!